# What is best practice for passing variables via GET?

Tags: django, django-views

I am passing a variable in my URL:

```
mydomain.com/app/?next_page=my_page
```

I can get this variable in a `view` with:

```
def mypage(request):
   var = request.GET['next_page']
```

Is it best practice to also change the URL to require `next_page`? Something along the lines of:

```
path('app/?nextpage=<str>', mypage, name='my_page')
```

What's best practice? If so, what's the correct syntax for this (I know the example is incorrect)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs.

Do not define a fixed url route; if you use the query parameters for filtering and there is more than one possible parameter

```
Example: "app/photos?size=100x100" and "app/photos/?color=blue"
```

Define a fixed url route; if it will be the same for each and every page, like details of a particular page:

```
Example: "app/orders/123123123" and "app/orders/123123123"
```

Btw, the correct syntax is:

```
path(app/<str:next_page>/, mypage, name="my_page")
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the syntax for the referrer without HTTP_REQUEST?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at path patterns. Enforcing a GET parameter in a path is not really a good practice. So if you want to require a username for example you can use:

```
path('bio/<username>/', views.bio, name='bio'),
```

You can find more patterns in Django documentation to catch strings, slugs, integers etc.

And in views you should define your function as such:

```
def mypage(request, username):
    ...code...
```

About GET:

Keep in mind that `request.GET["value"]` will raise a ValueError if that parameter does not exist. So you can catch that error to inform user that they are missing a parameter. (This will make this parameter obligatory.)

You can also use `request.GET.get("value")` which will return None if the key does not exist. If you want to use a default parameter you can use of course,  `request.GET.get("value", "default")`

You can use as many parameters as you want in your link with or without path patterns. Their values will be stored in `request.GET`

Comment: Thanks, which is best practice and what would the syntax look like for the referrer?

Comment: If something should always be present, you should use patterns. Otherwise you should stick to GET parameters. In your example you are referring to next page which is not always present. In this case you should make use of GET parameter. Of course sometimes you need both. They are not interchangeably the same.

Comment: Referrer is embedded in request.META, not in request.GET